# Regexp with variables: how to convert xml with attributes to html using javascript replace method?

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, replace

Apologies if this is a dup, I searched but couldn't quite find the info I was looking for.

Using javascript, I want to search a string, find a tag, match attributes in the tag, and store them as variables for rewriting.  Here's the part of the string I'm looking for:

```
<my_child name="view" gso="g--" type="Application.View">
```

that I'd like to convert to:

```
<tr><td>view</td><td>Appication.View</td><td>g--</td></tr>
```

Here's the regexp I'm trying.  I don't think it's actually finding a match though:

```
objString = objString.replace(/<my_child name="(.*)" gso="(.*)" type="(.*)">/g, '<tr><td>'+RegExp.$1+'</td><td>'+RegExp.$3+'</td><td>'+RegExp.$2+'</td><td>');
```

EDIT: SOLVED.

Thanks for the advice kiamlaluno.  Turns out I was also not taking into account the indeterminate number of spaces between attributes.  Here's the updated regexp:

```
/<my_child[ ]+name="([^"]*)"[ ]+gso="([^"]*)"[ ]+type="([^"]*)"[ ]*>/g, '<tr><td>$1</td><td>$3</td><td>$2</td><td>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace

```
'<tr><td>'+RegExp.$1+'</td><td>'+RegExp.$3+'</td><td>'+RegExp.$2+'</td><td>'
```

with

```
'<tr><td>$1</td><td>$3</td><td>$2</td><td>'
```

and the `(.*)` matches should probably be `([^"]*)` instead

maybe that will help get you closer?

Comment: Thanks, I've got it now.  One of the issues was an indeterminate number of spaces between the parameters.